# PIE does just not apply at all

Tags: internet-explorer, behavior, css

So I try to use PIE.htc to render box-shadow for IE7/8. I set everything up according to the documentation, but it just won't work, no shadows, whether in IE8 nor 7. I quatriple checked the documentation and demos on [css3 pie](http://css3pie.com/), I googled a LOT and analysed my implementation, but I just can't find the source of the problem. There's another thread here about the same problem from two months ago, but no solution either. I really hope someone sees what I may have made wrong, oh and just to avoid useless comments, i already tried using PIE.php, doesn't work either.

Some images attached for more information.

Inspect with IE Developer Tools
[image: IE Developer Tools]

Getting the source directly
[image: Trying to get the source]

My CSS
[image: CSS]

Comment: Two questions: Have you confirmed that PIE is working on your page elsewhere? and Have you tried the solutions [here](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#z-index)

Comment: Have you tried to turn off/remove the filter you have at the bottom of your css or putting the behavior at the bottom after the filter as the filter could be overwriting the PIE.htc.

Comment: @ trickeedickee: yeah I read something about putting the behavior rule at the bottom, but it didn't change anything
@ Josh Farneman: like I said I really checked the whole css3 pie page multiple times, but PIE won't work on any of my pages, this pic is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really strange, after some (random) adjustments it suddenly gets applied after a page load, but just in 1 of 10 times... and when it gets applied it destroys the layout of some buttons (they shrink in width without a reason). We will probably just scope the project down to shadowless buttons in IE8-...